# HDMI display port not detected on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm trying to connect a Lenovo Legion 5i Gen 7 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel `6.5.0-21-generic`) to an external monitor LG 27gp850p-b. The `Displays` shows only my primary display and `xrandr --auto` shows nothing. `xrandr --query` shows the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm ...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and `xrandr --verbose` shows the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  13938
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.54:1.0:1.7
    Brightness: 0.73
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009e51c0a00000000
        0d1f0104b52213780754a5a7544c9b26
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101b99c80a0703859403020
        360058c21000001a000000fd003ca5c1
        c128010a202020202020000000fe0042
        4f452043510a202020202020000000fe
        004e5631353646484d2d4e59380a0040
    vrr_capable: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    panel orientation: Normal 
        supported: Normal, Upside Down, Left Side Up, Right Side Up
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: -97228368 0 67911409 0 4555994 -2147483648 40159710 0 -28429073 0 3193240 -2147483648 32617329 0 24203080 0 
        -44098461 0 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 236 
        supported: 236
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x46) 401.210MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock 192.89KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1089 total 1169           clock 165.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x47) 381.303MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock 183.32KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock 165.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x48) 327.895MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock 178.20KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock 165.00Hz
  1400x1050 (0x49) 335.644MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock 178.53KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock 165.00Hz
  1600x900 (0x4a) 268.916MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock 152.79KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock 165.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4b) 296.909MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock 175.89KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock 165.00Hz
  1400x900 (0x4c) 238.357MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock 152.79KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock 165.00Hz
  1280x960 (0x4d) 297.006MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock 165.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock 165.00Hz
  1368x768 (0x4e) 199.179MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock 130.35KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock 165.00Hz
  1280x800 (0x4f) 195.549MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock 135.80KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock 165.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x50) 237.605MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock 148.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock 165.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x51) 176.065MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock 122.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock 165.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x52) 178.742MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock 132.99KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock 165.00Hz
  1024x768i (0x53) 85.198MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1024 start 1032 end 1208 total 1264 skew    0 clock  67.40KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  776 total  817           clock 165.00Hz
  960x720 (0x54) 321.757MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock 247.51KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock 165.00Hz
  928x696 (0x55) 299.916MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock 237.28KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock 165.00Hz
  896x672 (0x56) 281.538MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock 230.01KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock 165.00Hz
  1024x576 (0x57) 115.851MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  97.85KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock 165.00Hz
  960x600 (0x58) 211.759MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock 203.61KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock 165.00Hz
  832x624 (0x59) 126.786MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock 110.06KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock 165.00Hz
  960x540 (0x5a) 102.751MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  91.74KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock 165.00Hz
  800x600 (0x5b) 105.602MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock 103.13KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock 165.00Hz
  840x525 (0x5c) 163.947MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock 178.20KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock 165.00Hz
  864x486 (0x5d) 84.481MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  82.50KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock 165.00Hz
  700x525 (0x5e) 167.822MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock 178.53KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock 165.00Hz
  800x450 (0x5f) 134.458MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock 152.79KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock 165.00Hz
  640x512 (0x60) 148.454MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock 175.89KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock 165.00Hz
  700x450 (0x61) 119.178MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock 152.79KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock 165.00Hz
  640x480 (0x62) 69.301MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  86.63KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock 165.00Hz
  720x405 (0x63) 60.840MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  69.14KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock 165.00Hz
  720x400 (0x64) 68.881MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  756 end  828 total  936 skew    0 clock  73.59KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  446           clock 165.00Hz
  684x384 (0x65) 99.589MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock 130.35KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock 165.00Hz
  640x400 (0x66) 61.091MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  73.43KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  445           clock 165.00Hz
  576x432 (0x67) 118.802MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  672 total  800 skew    0 clock 148.50KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  450           clock 165.00Hz
  640x360 (0x68) 49.369MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  61.71KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock 165.00Hz
  640x350 (0x69) 61.091MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  73.43KHz
        v: height  350 start  382 end  385 total  445           clock 165.00Hz
  512x384 (0x6a) 89.371MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock 132.99KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock 165.00Hz
  512x384i (0x6b) 42.547MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  516 end  604 total  632 skew    0 clock  67.32KHz
        v: height  384 start  384 end  388 total  408           clock 165.00Hz
  512x288 (0x6c) 57.827MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  97.68KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock 165.00Hz
  416x312 (0x6d) 63.298MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   416 start  432 end  464 total  576 skew    0 clock 109.89KHz
        v: height  312 start  312 end  314 total  333           clock 165.00Hz
  480x270 (0x6e) 51.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  91.74KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock 165.00Hz
  400x300 (0x6f) 52.716MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock 102.96KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock 165.00Hz
  432x243 (0x70) 42.240MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  82.50KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock 165.00Hz
  320x240 (0x71) 34.584MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  86.46KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock 165.00Hz
  360x202 (0x72) 30.347MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  68.97KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock 165.00Hz
  360x200 (0x73) 34.440MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  378 end  414 total  468 skew    0 clock  73.59KHz
        v: height  200 start  200 end  202 total  223           clock 165.00Hz
  320x200 (0x74) 30.476MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  336 end  368 total  416 skew    0 clock  73.26KHz
        v: height  200 start  200 end  202 total  222           clock 165.00Hz
  320x180 (0x75) 24.684MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  61.71KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock 165.00Hz
  320x175 (0x76) 30.476MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  336 end  368 total  416 skew    0 clock  73.26KHz
        v: height  175 start  191 end  192 total  222           clock 165.00Hz
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  13938
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    subconnector: Unknown 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 245 
        supported: 245
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  13938
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    subconnector: Unknown 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 258 
        supported: 258
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

The HDMI port is not listed. Having googled that HDMI might be related to GPU which is Nvidia in my case, I tried upgrading drivers, `sudo update-drivers autoinstall`, which resulted in the following nvidia-smi.

[image: nvidia-smi]

Downgrading the drivers to <=515 is not possible due to some incompatibility errors (cannot reinstall the whole CUDA support due to other software that relies on the current setup). Secure boot is disabled.

Also adding `inxi -Gxx` results:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics vendor: Lenovo
    driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:46a6
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia v: 535.161.07 pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:24e0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9
    driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 98
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: BOE Display res: 1920x1080 dpi: 142
    diag: 395mm (15.5")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes
```

Could you suggest next troubleshooting steps?

I verified that the hardware works fine by switching to Windows and seamlessly connecting to the monitor there.

Answer (score 1):

The following helped to resolve the problem in my case:

1. `grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/*`
2. in the output, find a file that contains `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`
3. open this file and replace `options nvidia-drm modeset=0` with `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`
4. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
5. `reboot`

Upon reboot, the HDMI port is detected and the monitor is automatically connected.